# Эмулировать keydown на элементе страницы

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser, keydown

Есть программа с компонентом WebBrowser и текстовое поле на сайте, которое перехватывает keydown. До этого работал через focus и sendkeys, но проблема в том, что при переключении на другое окно перестает работать. После чего написал такую команду:

```
mainweb.Url = new Uri("javascript:" +
            "document.getElementById('double_your_btc_stake').value = '0.000002';" +
            "document.getElementById('double_your_btc_stake').dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {keyCode: 0x20}));");
```

Но, к сожалению, вот это:

```
document.getElementById('double_your_btc_stake').dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {keyCode: 0x20}));
```

не работает в IE. В консоли самого IE пишет "Команда не поддерживается объектом.

Кто может подсказать программную эмуляцию keydown на элементе страницы в webbrowser?

UPD: Нашел вот такое решение, его IE принимает:

```
$(document.getElementById('double_your_btc_stake')).keydown();
```

но, если делать так:

```
 mainweb.Url = new Uri("javascript:$(document.getElementById('double_your_btc_stake')).keydown();");
```

то объект результата выводится в WebBrowser в виде [Object object], а нужно оставаться на странице.

Comment: Если Вы решили проблему самостоятельно, пожалуйста, оформите решение в качестве ответа.

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент решение найдено:

```
        mainweb.Document.GetElementById("double_your_btc_stake").SetAttribute("value", "0.000002");
        HtmlDocument doc = mainweb.Document;
        HtmlElement head = doc.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement s = doc.CreateElement("script");
        s.SetAttribute("text", "function keyEvent() { $(document.getElementById('double_your_btc_stake')).keydown(); }");
        head.AppendChild(s);
        mainweb.Document.InvokeScript("keyEvent");
```